# Name hiding for declarations which made visible by a using-directive

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[basic.scope.hiding]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.hiding#4) says:

> During the lookup of a name qualified by a namespace name, declarations that would otherwise be made visible by a using-directive can be hidden by declarations with the same name in the namespace containing the using-directive; see [namespace.qual].

I've failed the come up with an example, where [basic.scope.hiding]/4 actually in effect, and makes a difference (because other rules, like [[namespace.udir]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udir#2) already handles the situtation).

Can you give a simple (easy to understand) example of this rule?

Comment: [basic.scope.hiding]/4 refers only to qualified lookup, and [namespace.udir]/2 implies hiding only for unqualified lookup.

Comment: @aschepler: thanks, somehow I missed that little-tiny detail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is simply in qualified vs. unqualified lookup:

```
namespace A {
    int x;
    int y;
}

namespace B {
    using namespace A;
    int x;
    int test1() {
        return x + y; // [namespace.udir]/2
    }
}

int test2() {
    return B::x + B::y; // [basic.scope.hiding]/4
}
```

Comment: What does `B::x` in `test2` hide?

Comment: It hides the otherwise would-be imported `A::x`.

Comment: But `return x + B::y;` will not even compile.

Comment: [basic.scope.hiding]/4 simply talks about *qualified* lookup. So `B::x`, no more.

Comment: Just trying to understand. How is `A::x` is imported into `test2`?

Comment: It isn't, because `B::x` hides it. But `A::y` is imported by the [`using` declaration](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.namespace#namespace.udecl-1) and becomes visible through `B::y`.